# Get with PHP Array Tree Values Recursively with start and stop limit level

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am making a module for creating navigation menus and I would like to give the possibility to set an initial and final level. I have this array tree with level how can return it setting a start level and stop level ? this is my function that return empty.

Original Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [pid] => 12
            [level] => 0
            [children] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [pid] => 12
            [level] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 27
                            [pid] => 24
                            [level] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 28
                                            [pid] => 27
                                            [level] => 2
                                            [children] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [pid] => 12
            [level] => 0
            [children] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [pid] => 12
            [level] => 0
            [children] => 
        )

)
```

My function:

```
function get_tree_limit ($pages, $start_level, $stop_level) {

    $result = Array();

    foreach( $pages as $page ) {

        $children = Array();

        if(isset($page['children'])){
            $children = get_tree_limit ($page['children'], $start_level, $stop_level);
        }

        if($page['level'] >= $start_level && $page['level'] <= $stop_level){

            $result[] = Array(
                'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'],
                'children' => $children
            );

        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

if I try:

```
$rpage = get_tree_limit ($pages, 1, 2);
print_r($rpage);
```

The result is empty:

```
Array()
```

Where I am wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that at level 0, although you set `$children` - you never add this anywhere to be returned.

Comment: @NigelRen that should return the array empty if no children. If I remove the condition start and stop level return correct. But of coarse my concept is wrong or I solved my  self. Can you write the correct fuction or difficult to understand. Thanks.

Comment: what is in $pages?

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan $pages of coarse is the original array you can see at the top of the post.

Comment: Scope of $result variable is  in function only and return value is only for key 0 and your start level is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During simple `foreach` loop you need to check the main index `children` and in case of it has array datatype you need to turn on recursive action (use *is_array($page['children'])*):

```
if(is_array($page['children'])){ } else {  }
```

In case of non-array you can just append this values to the result array if the `level` is in range:

```
if(   $page['level'] >= $start_level 
   && $page['level'] <= $stop_level 
   && is_numeric($page['level'])
  ){
     $result[$ind] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 
                        'children' => $page['children']
     ); 
}
```

In case of array datatype you need to do the same, but with recursive action:

```
if(  $page['level'] >= $start_level 
  && $page['level'] <= $stop_level 
  && is_numeric($page['level'])){ 

  $result[$ind] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 
                        'children' => @get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'] 
  );   
}

if (!isset($result[$ind]) ) {
    if (@count(get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'])>0){
        $result[$ind] = @get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'];
    }
}
```

**@** hides **warnings**, so the result body of the function looks like next:

```
$result = Array();

foreach($pages as $ind => $page ) {

        if(is_array($page['children'])){ 

           if($page['level'] >= $start_level 
           && $page['level'] <= $stop_level 
           && is_numeric($page['level'])){ 
                //print_r($page);
                $result[$ind] = Array(
                    'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 
                    'children' => @get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'] 
                );   
            }

            if (!isset($result[$ind]) ) {
               if (@count(get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'])>0){
                    $result[$ind] = @get_tree_limit($page, $start_level, $stop_level)['children'];
               }
            } 

        } else {
            if($page['level'] >= $start_level && $page['level'] <= $stop_level && is_numeric($page['level'])){
                $result[$ind] = Array(
                    'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 
                    'children' => $page['children']
                ); 
            } 
        } 
}

return $result;
```

For example, `$res = get_tree_limit($ar, 2, 3);` returns only **2** and **3** levels of the tree:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [pid] => 27
            [level] => 2
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 29
                    [pid] => 28
                    [level] => 3
                    [children] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e6a75fceea2ec8f1a31f637d92bf1816477abe9)**

You can choose any level range and you'll get correspond tree branch.

Comment: Your code does its job and looks very clean. Compliments! I've always said that programmers should write code and avoid words :) Thanks

Comment: testing your code I check that there is a small problem. if Start or Stop limit is 0 should be ignored. What I mean if you set start_level = 2 and stop_level = 0 should show level 2, 3. same start level 0 stop level 2 should show level 0,1,2. is start_level=0 and stop_level=0 should to show 0,1,2,3.

Comment: @DaebakDo, no, it works as a **range** - you can choose **from** level **to** level. 0-0 - gives 0 levels, 0-1 - gives first 2, 1-2 - gives **1** and **2**

Comment: If you wanna I can fix this with your wishes.

Comment: thanks you are really kind. By the way if children doesn't exist return error. For this my code was so long :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203462/discussion-between-daebak-do-and-aksen-p).

Comment: @DaebakDo, yeap, you could add many checks as you wish,[take a look](https://3v4l.org/qFl4p)

Comment: the structure of your array is different please can you check it thanks. Original [children] => Array([0] => Array([id] => 27... and not [children] => Array(Array([id] => 27..

Comment: `isset` and `is_array` are different functions. Also, you have a weird conditions in if statement, such as `<0`

Comment: yes but my meaning is that your starting array of pages has a different structure of mine. By the way I can change it from [children]=>Array([0]=>Array) in [children]=>Array(Array

Comment: I still have problem please check your code in this demo https://3v4l.org/ngiUV your code work with your array $ar but is different with the array of my post array $ar2. Thanks.

Comment: @DaebakDo, I can't figure out what is your issue. Ok, here is [code](https://3v4l.org/7nFUp) for `$ar2` structure. It is it?

Comment: from your demo https://3v4l.org/7nFUp you can see that the result produce: Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 28

and not

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28

Comment: @DaebakDo, you need to remove Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] =>?

Comment: @DaebakDo, like [this](https://3v4l.org/iuXdi)? (you can comment sort at the end and save main indexes)

Comment: :( please check it still have problem ar3 thanks. https://3v4l.org/0tvTP

Comment: the line that generate the problem is 104 I fixed removing [0] but in this way generate extra key. For fix I added a function that clean the extra key if you have a solution integrated is welcome. Please check this demo https://3v4l.org/DFgjJ

Answer (score 0):

Ok this function does its job and I insert if someone is looking for it and to receive some suggestions. I also added the control in the case start and stop are null.

```
function get_tree_limit ($pages, $start_level, $stop_level) {

    $result = Array();

    foreach($pages as $page) {

        $children = Array();

        if(isset($page['children'])){
            $children = get_tree_limit ($page['children'], $start_level, $stop_level);
        }

        if($start_level > 0 && $stop_level > 0){

            if(!empty($children)){

                if($page['level'] >= $start_level && $page['level'] <= $stop_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 'children' => $children
                    );

                } else {

                    $result = $children;

                }

            } else {

                if($page['level'] >= $start_level && $page['level'] <= $stop_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level']
                    );

                }

            }

        } elseif($start_level <= 0 && $stop_level > 0) {

            if(!empty($children)){

                if($page['level'] <= $stop_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 'children' => $children
                    );

                } else {

                    $result = $children;

                }

            } else {

                if($page['level'] <= $stop_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level']
                    );

                }

            }

        } elseif($start_level > 0 && $stop_level <= 0) {

            if(!empty($children)){

                if($page['level'] >= $start_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 'children' => $children
                    );

                } else {

                    $result = $children;

                }

            } else {

                if($page['level'] >= $start_level){

                    $result[] = Array(
                        'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level']
                    );

                }

            }

        } else {

            if(!empty($children)){

                $result[] = Array(
                    'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level'], 'children' => $children
                );

            } else {

                $result[] = Array(
                    'id' => $page['id'], 'pid' => $page['pid'], 'level' => $page['level']
                );              

            }

        }

    }

    return $result;

}
```

test

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e9b1822d294f0af65f81a8ad9ce5f61db7e43f7

Comment: [It doesn't works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86a7b17eda895accbfe033f2d8c4739d387d7614)

Comment: why if I pass the array and debug all the ase return me the correct array.

Comment: @AksenP you can test here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e9b1822d294f0af65f81a8ad9ce5f61db7e43f7

Comment: And what? **0** to **0** gives **0** to **2** :D You're failed.

Comment: @AksenP Change it